# Ordering MySQL 8 results by count existence in a crosswalk table

Tags: mysql, count, sql-order-by

I have the following MySQL 8 tables:

```
[submissions]
===
id
submission_type
name

[reject_reasons]
===
id
name

[submission_reject_reasons] -- crosswalk joining the first 2 tables
===
id
submission_id
reject_reason_id
```

In my application, users can submit submissions, and other users can request changes to those submissions. When they request these rejections, 1+ entries get saved to the `submission_reject_reasons` table (which stores the ID of the submission for which rejections are requested, as well as the ID of the reason for why the rejection is being made). So a typical entry in the table might look like:

```
id      submission_id     reject_reason_id
==============================================
45      384               294
```

Where `submission_id = 384` is the "Fizz Buzz" submission and `reject_reason_id = 294` is the "*Missing Required Field*" reason.

I currently have a query that fetches all the `reject_reasons` out of the DB:

```
SELECT * FROM reject_reasons
```

I now want to modify this query to sort the results based on their usage frequency. Meaning the query might currently return:

```
294 | Missing Required Field
14 | Malformed Entry
1885 | Makes No Sense
```

etc. But lets say there are 5 entries in the `submission_reject_reasons` table where 294 (Missing Required Field) is the `reject_reason_id`, and say there are 15 enries where 1885 (Makes No Sense) is present, and 120 entries where 14 (Malformed Entry) are present. I need a query that returns all `reject_reasons` sorted by their count in the `submission_reject_reasons` (SRR) table, descending, so that the most frequently used appear earlier in the sort. Hence the result set would be:

```
14 | Malformed Entry --> because there are 120 instances of this in the SRR table
1885 | Makes No Sense --> because there are 15 instances in the SRR
294 | Missing Required Field --> because there are only 5 instances in the SRR
```

Furthermore, I need a ranking from most-used to least-used. If a reason doesn't exist in the SRR table it should have a default "count" of zero (0) but should still come back in the query. If 2+ reason counts are tied, then I don't care how they are sorted. Any ideas here? I need the final result set to only contain the `rr.id` and `rr.name` field/values.

My best attempt is not getting me anywhere:

```
SELECT rr.id, rr.name
FROM reject_reasons AS rr
LEFT JOIN submission_reject_reasons AS srr on rr.id = srr.reject_reason_id
GROUP BY rr.id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Can anyone help me over the finish line here? Can anyone spot where I'm goin awry? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be grouping by the reject reason ID. `COUNT(*)` is what you want to count in each group.

```
SELECT rr.id, rr.name
FROM reject_reasons AS rr
JOIN submission_reject_reasons AS srr on rr.id = srr.reject_reason_id
GROUP BY rr.id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

There's no need for any `EXISTS` check, since the `INNER JOIN` won't return any reject reasons that don't exist in `submission_reject_reasons`.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar (+1) -- is there _any_ way to refine this so that `COUNT (*) AS rrCnt` is _not_ a column in the returned result set (so that only `rr.*` fields such as `rr.id` and `rr.name` are in the result set)? Thanks again so much!

Comment: Apologies @Barmar (+1) but after testing this, it is not correct. It sorts the #1 most-used reason to the top of the result set, but doesn't go any further than that; whereas I need a ranking from most used to least used. I changed your query to be a `LEFT JOIN` so that reasons that don't exist on the SRR table still get pulled back in the query results. If a reason doesn't exist in the SRR table it should have a default "count" of zero (0). If 2+ reason counts are tied, then I don't care how they are sorted. Any ideas here? Thanks again so much!

Comment: If you use LEFT JOIN then you must use `COUNT(srr.id)` to get zero counts.

Comment: You edited the question to show my answer instead of your attempt. Please put back your original code, to provide the proper context to my answer.

Comment: Can you create a sqlfiddle that demonstrates the problem?